# elision of "with his"

Tags: elision

[image]

I hear this line she just pronounced "with his" as "tis". This is the way the native speakers do?

It always makes me frustrated. Even after studying English more than 2 decades, can't understand the simplest lines in TV series.

Comment: Not sure why you write "with this" when then image says "with his".  Some speakers of American English might say "wit is" there, making a hard T instead of the dental fricative, and giving no breath no the 'h' of "his".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, my mistake 

Comment: Could you provide a link to the clip, perhaps on YouTube?

Comment: @Tashus, I found this, http://www.kekenet.com/video/201804/550510.shtml If it doesn't work, I'll upload one.